# Snowflake Insert locked table

Tags: java, connection-pooling, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a API that uses JBDC connection pool to insert (only insert and select API calls) records in Snowflake. When i configure the connection pool size > 20

```
net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: Statement 'YY' has locked table 'XXX' in transaction ZZ and this lock has not yet been released.
```

I am using Java and dbcp2 for connection pool. Below is my code sample

```
try{
    conn = snowflakeconnection.getDataSource().getConnection();
    conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(INSERTSQL);
    pstmt.executeQuery();
    conn.commit();
}  catch (Exception e) {
    conn.rollback();
} finally {
    if (!conn.isClosed()) {
    conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    conn.close();
}
}
```

I am not sure why i am getting Table locked for insert statement in Snowflake. The code works fine when i configure the connection pool < 20 and I am not getting table locked exception. I did looked into the snowflake forum and community but i did not get the explanation for this. Can you please help me on this. ? and what went wrong here.

Comment: Is it always failing with connection pool > 20? Can you confirm if there is any DML statement running in parallel which has acquired a lock on the table. (Like update, delete). Also are you committing manually as auto-commit is set to False. If a transaction is not committed a lock on the table won't be release even after successful execution.

Comment: Hi @Zonera- Thanks for your comment, 1. Insert is the only statement running against that table (i have created it to test) so no other process/application is accessing it. 2. I have the rollback if there are any exception and doing commit on success insert finally closing connection as i have mentioned in my code in the question.

Comment: It is likely that you are queuing up your INSERT statements behind the first insert statement.  Snowflake limits the number of statements to 20 before it starts erroring out.  I recommend looking at your query_history from the Snowflake UI and seeing what is happening.  As a note, Snowflake is not built for 1 record inserts like this (not OLTP).  I'd recommend that you batch up your insert statements instead.

Comment: As Mike Walton mentioned Snowflake doesn't work well with single row inserts rather it's an overhead. Better change to bulk load to mitigate the issue.

Comment: Hi @MikeWalton - This helps a lot.